# is there a way to detect if a resource was pulled from cache or server using fetch()

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add instrumentation code to calculate the total time a client takes to fetch a resource(image, video...) from server.

This is the code:

```
const response = await fetch(url, {headers});
```

This response is loaded into a HTMLImageElement using `new Iamge()` and `src` is pointed to url of the blob using `createObjectURL`.

I want to ignore the request time if the image was pulled from cache. I see the message in chrome dev tools next to response status (`from disk cache`).

is there a way to access it in my code ?

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12830425/how-to-detect-when-xhr-returns-a-cached-resource

Comment: I am performing a cors call and Date is not part of the simple headers. Need to check if that can be added to the backed using `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`